# Getting IndexError when translating Least Square Method from C into Python

Tags: python

My code describes a COVID-19 approaching with Least Square Method. I was trying to adapt C code into Python, like this.

**C code:**

```c
float gbarra1[224] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
float a[224] = {};
float b[224] = {};
float d[224]= {};
float f[224]={};
float g[224]={};
cont = 0, i = 0;
while (cont<224){
    for (i=cont; i<cont+28;i++){            
            
    a[i]=a[i-1]+gbarra1[i];
    b[i]=b[i-1]+a[i]; 
    d[i]=d[i-1]+a[i]*a[i];
    f[i]=f[i-1]+data[i];
    g[i]=g[i-1]+data[i]*t[i];
    x[i]=(-d[i]*f[i]+b[i]*g[i])/(b[i]*b[i]-a[i]*d[i]);
    y[i]=(b[i]*f[i]-a[i]*g[i])/(b[i]*b[i]-a[i]*d[i]);

    res[i]=x[i]+y[i]*t[i];
    r0[i]=exp(y[i]*5.4);

    erro_aux[i]=erro_aux[i+1]+(((casosAc[i]-res[i])*(casosAc[i]-res[i]))); //First part of error
    erro[i]=sqrt(erro_aux[i])/28; //Total error
    par_a[i]=exp(x[i]);
```

**Python code**

```
g1 = [0.0]*(len(dados))
for i in range(len(dados)):
    g1.append(1)
...
a = [0.0]*(len(dados))
b = [0.0]*(len(dados))
f = [0.0]*(len(dados))
d = [0.0]*(len(dados))
g = [0.0]*(len(dados))
x = [0.0]*(len(dados))
y = [0.0]*(len(dados))
r0 = [0.0]*(len(dados))
final = [0.0]*(len(dados))
er = [0.0]*(len(dados))
er2 = [0.0]*(len(dados))
p_a = [0.0]*(len(dados))

length = 28
cont = 0
som = 0
day = 28

while cont < len(dados):
    i = cont
    while i < (cont+28):
        a[i] = (a[i-1] + g1[i])
        b[i] = (b[i-1] + a[i])
        d[i] = (d[i-1]+a[i] * a[i])
        f[i] = (f[i-1] + dados[i])
        g[i] = (g[i-1] + dados[i] * t[i])
        x[i] = ((-d[i] * f[i] + b[i] * g[i]) / (b[i] * b[i] - a[i] * d[i]))
        y[i] = ((b[i] * f[i] - a[i] * g[i]) / (b[i] * b[i] - a[i] * d[i]))
        
        final[i] = (x[i] + y[i] * t[i])
        r0[i] = (np.exp(y[i] * 5.4))
        er2[i] = er2[i+1] + (((dados[i] - final[i]) * (dados[i] - final[i])))
        er[i] = (np.sqrt(er2[i])/day)
        p_a[i] = (np.exp(x[i]))

        i+=1

     writer.writerow([dados[cont], final[cont], x[cont], p_a[cont], y[cont], er[cont]])
     cont+=1
```

But I got some errors like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/dev/kivy/main.py", line 49, in <module>
    a[i] = (a[i-1] + g1[i])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

After implementing the `a = [0.0]*224`, I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/dev/kivy/main.py", line 69, in <module>
    er2[i] = er2[i+1] + (((dados[i] - final[i]) * (dados[i] - final[i])))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

The C code declares the arrays to be length 224, but in Python they are created as empty lists.  You can fix it by changing:

```
a = list()
b = list()
f = list()
d = list()
g = list()
```

to:

```
a = [0.0] * 224
b = [0.0] * 224
f = [0.0] * 224
d = [0.0] * 224
g = [0.0] * 224
```

This will initialize them to length 224 with all values being `0.0`.

If you don't need to rely on the initial values being `0.0`, you can use `[None] * 224` instead.  That way you'll get an error if you try to do arithmetic on any of the uninitialized values.

Update:  The code in the original post has incorporated the above bug fix (with a different length calculation), so this answer no longer applies to the current code.

However, one major problem with the posted code is that, on the first iteration, `i` is `0`, so `i-1` is `-1`.  This results in many attempts to index outside of the arrays (lists).  For example:

```
a[i] = (a[i-1] + g1[i])
```

When `i` is `0`, this becomes:

```
a[0] = (a[-1] + g1[0])
```

Note the reference to `a[-1]`.  This is a bug in the C and Python code, but in Python, it detects and reports the error at runtime.  The C code will just pick up whatever values happen to be outside of the arrays.

Comment: i used that and got the same error.

Comment: Ok, it looks like there's another variable that needs to be defined, called `g1` in your Python code.  Where is that defined?  Please fix your post to include *all* of the relevant code, not just some of it.  All I can say with certainty is that the code I posted will allow indices in the range 0 through 223 for `a`, `b`, `d`, `f`, and `g`.

Comment: Whatever bug you have is clearly trivial, but you have not posted a [mre], so a more complete solution than what I provided is not possible.

Comment: I fixed the post with most important parts of the code, sorry about that

Comment: Ok, it looks like your length calculations aren't quite right.  I don't see where `dados` is set, but it looks like it's being used to set the length of your arrays (e.g., 224 in the original C code).  Now, in the outer loop, `cont` can be as high as `len(dados) - 1`.  Then, in the inner loop, `i` can be as high as `cont + 27`.  So `i` can be as high as `len(dados) + 26`.  So your arrays (lists) are too short.

Comment: Also, on the very first iteration, `i` is zero, so `i - 1` is `-1`, which is an invalid index. Note that your C code appears to have the same bug, but in the case of C it will just pick up some garbage value, which in Python you will get an error.  I suggest sitting down, and *carefully* figuring out *exactly* what loop bounds you want.

Comment: In the **C code**, i have a dot product between vectors `g1 * g1 = a`, `g1 * g2 = b` (where `g2` is a  time vector from `1 to len(dados)` about 560 length), `g2 * g2 = d`, `f(x) * g1 = f` (where `f(x)` is the vector `dados`), `f(x) * g2 = g` and `x` and `y` it's a linear algebric manipulation with the vectors.

Comment: That still won't handle the case where `i` is `0`, and therefore `i-1` is `-1`.  As I said, this is a bug in the C code as well as the Python code.  The difference is that your C code is indexing outside of the arrays, picking up undefined values, while the Python code is detecting the bug and throwing an error.

Comment: In both versions (C and Python), on the very first iteration, `i` is `0`, right?  Now look at what it's doing.  The very first assignment is `a[i] = (a[i-1] + g1[i])`.  So `a[0] = (a[-1] + g1[0])` That's a bug, because `i-1` is `-1`.  It's indexing outside of the array with `a[-1]`.  You're picking up an undefined value.  It's a severe bug.  It needs to be fixed in both the C and the Python versions.

Comment: I changed that `a[i-1]` and got stuck whith same error :c

Comment: Working with **dot product** with the `numpy.dot` will work?

Comment: It doesn't matter what package you use.  You aren't going to be able to index outside of an array.  So, don't do it.  Again, you need to think it through and figure out what you want.  You haven't done that, so you're getting lots of bugs.  I'd definitely stick with Python for now, since it will at least detect *some* of the bugs for you.  With C, it will silently pick up unknown values.

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer to describe the problem when `i` is `0`.  There are many ways you could skip this, but they may not do what you want.  For example, one obvious way would be to change `i = cont` to `i = cont + 1`.  This would avoid the `-1` index, but it would skip the first iteration of the inner loop.  A different way to be to instead change `cont = 0` to `cont = 1`, skipping the first iteration of the *outer* loop.  Whether or not either of these will do what you want is something you need to determine.

Comment: I uptade the code and now it runs, but i don't know if the results are right. I add a `if i == len(dados): break` to end the code before **i** begin bigger than the vectors. Code here: [link](https://pastebin.com/0eakzGip)

Comment: Yes, that was my concern.  It avoids the out-of-bounds indexing error, but the logic may not be right.  On the other hand, it can't be worse than it was (or than the C version is).  Again, you need to decide what you want it to do.  Your C version is quite likely producing incorrect results, and worse, any time you recompile it, the behavior could change (that's why you never, ever write C programs that have undefined behavior, like indexing outside of an array).